# How to increase/decrease element font-size on click event using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, font-size

I am doing a site for the visually impaired. I have three button:

1. <kbd>increase font</kbd>
2. <kbd>reduce the font</kbd>
3. <kbd>in normal mode</kbd>

I need by clicking add `+2` pixels for `font-size` for the class `*`. Please help how it can I be implemented in javascript.

Comment: Did you try anything already? Provide some existing code, otherwise no one will be happy to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JQUERY**

```
 size=parseInt($('p').css('font-size'));


    $("#big").on("click",function(){

      size=size+2;
       $("p").css("font-size",size + "px");
    });
    $("#normal").on("click",function(){
      size=14;
       $("p").css("font-size",size + "px");
    });
    $("#small").on("click",function(){
      size=size-2;
       $("p").css("font-size",size+ "px");
    });
```

**HTML**

```
 <p>CLICK ME!</p>
  <button id='big'>BIG</button>
  <button id='normal'>NORMAL</button>
  <button id='small'>SMALL</button>
```

**LINK** [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/gisenegilo/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard, actually

CSS:

```
// Set all inherited fonts to
body.impaired-view, body.impaired-view * {
    font-size: 150%;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
// Add the class 'impaired-view' to the body
function enlargeFont() {
    var body = document.querySelector('body');
    body.classList.add('impaired-view');
}

// Remove if not longer necceary
function shrinkFont() {
    var body = document.querySelector('body');
    body.classList.remove('impaired-view');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("yourElement").style.fontSize = yourValue;`

Answer (score 0):

**HTML, CSS, and jQuery:**

```js
var size = 18; // or any default number yo want
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bigger").click(function() {
    $("p").css("font-size", size + 1 + "px");
    size++;
  });
  $("#smaller").click(function() {
    $("p").css("font-size", size - 1 + "px");
    size--;
  });
  $("#moreBigger").click(function() {
    $("p").css("font-size", size + 2 + "px");
    size+=2;
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 18px
}
// or any default number you want
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Some Text</p>

<button id="bigger">Bigger</button>
<button id="smaller">Smaller</button>
<button id="moreBigger">More Bigger</button>
```

Comment: can make so that every time he added 2 pixels while the font-size will not exceed 30?

Comment: yes, you can, put it in an if condition: `if(size<30){$("p").css("font-size", size + 1 + "px"); size++}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sample code from [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7L2hh2u7/). It selects all elements with one class (you can change it to whatever you want), determines a current font size and assigns a bigger/smaller/default font to all of these elements.
A code sample:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#increaseBtn").click(function() {
    var textBoxes = $('.textClass');
    var fontSize = getCurrentFontSize(textBoxes);
    textBoxes.css("font-size", fontSize + 2);
  });
  
  $("#decreaseBtn").click(function() {
   var textBoxes = $('.textClass');
   var fontSize = getCurrentFontSize(textBoxes);
    textBoxes.css("font-size", fontSize - 2);
  });
  
  $("#defaultBtn").click(function() {
   $('.textClass').css("font-size", 12);
  });
});

function getCurrentFontSize(textBoxes) {
  var fontSize = textBoxes.eq(0).css("font-size");
  return parseInt(fontSize, 10);
}
```

```css
.textClass {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="textClass">Text1</div>
<div class="textClass">Text2</div>

<input type="button" id="increaseBtn" value="Incrase text size">
<input type="button" id="decreaseBtn" value="Decrease text size">
<input type="button" id="defaultBtn" value="Default text size">
```